# Faster left join with last non-empty

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2014

Table1:

- Shop
- Manager
- Date

Table2:

- Shop
- Date
- Sales

I need to get Table2 with Manager field from Table1. I did the following trick:

```
select
t1.[Shop]
,t1.[Date]
,t1.[Sum]
,t2.[Manager]
from t1 
left join t2
on t1.[Shop] = t2.[Shop] 
and t2.[Date] = (select max(t2.[Date]) from t2 
                 where t2.[Shop] = t1.[Shop] 
                 and t2.[Date] < t1.[Date])
```

It works, but subquerying is very slow, so I wonder if there is more elegant and fast way to do so?

Some sample data to play around: http://pastebin.com/uLN6x5JE

Comment: What DB and version?

Comment: Database: MSSQL2014.

Answer (score 0):

You may get much better performance by adding a covering index on t2 if you don't already have one:

```
create index T2ShopDate on t2 ([Shop], [Date]) include ([Manager])
```

Here is a version that uses a CTE to find all maximum manager dates first and then join back to t2 to get the manager:

```
;with MaxDates ([Shop], [Date], [Sum], [MaxMgrDate]) as
(
    select
        t1.[Shop]
        ,t1.[Date]
        ,t1.[Sum]
        ,max(t2.[Date])
    from t1
    left join t2
        on t2.[Shop] = t1.[Shop]
        and t2.[Date] < t1.[Date]
    group by
        t1.[Shop]
        ,t1.[Date]
        ,t1.[Sum]
)
select
    MaxDates.[Shop]
    ,MaxDates.[Date]
    ,MaxDates.[Sum]
    ,t2.[Manager]
from MaxDates
inner join t2
   on t2.[Date] = MaxDates.[MaxMgrDate]
```

You might be able to remove the second join back to t2 by using [`row_number()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx):

```
;with MaxDates ([Shop], [Date], [Sum], [Manager], [RowNum]) as
(
    select
        t1.[Shop]
        ,t1.[Date]
        ,t1.[Sum]
        ,t2.[Manager]
        ,row_number() over (partition by (t1.[Shop]) order by t2.[Date] desc)
    from t1
    left join t2
        on t2.[Shop] = t1.[Shop]
        and t2.[Date] < t1.[Date]
)
select *
from MaxDates
where RowNum = 1
```

Comment: Something wrong with your last group by, I need to generate a view, so CTE using isn't a good plan.

Comment: Oh. OK.  You didn't mention a view.

Answer (score 0):

may seem like a round about way but join on a single condition is typically  faster

```
select t12.[Shop], t12.[Date], t12.[Sum]
     , t12.[Manager]
from
(  select t1.[Shop], t1.[Date], t1.[Sum]
        , t2.[Manager] 
        , row_number() over (partition by t2.[Shop] order by t2.[Date] desc) as rn
     from t1 
     join t2
           on t2.[Shop] = t1.[Shop] 
          and t1.[Date] < t1.[Date]
) as t12 
where t12.rn = 1 
union 
select t1.[Shop], t1.[Date], t1.[Sum]
     , null as [Manager] 
 from t1 
 left join t2
        on t2.[Shop] = t1.[Shop] 
       and t1.[Date] < t1.[Date]
group by t1.[Shop], t1.[Date], t1.[Sum] 
having count(*) = 1
```

Comment: Hm, it generates wrong output, however row_number() is an interesting idea. I'll play around it.

Comment: Publish some sample data and expected output.

Comment: Added pastebin link with samples above.